# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : how to configure authentication and authorisation based on person department/role

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking for a little advice on how to implement my security requirements within ASP.NET Core 6.

Basically I have Company A who has multiple assets (Asset A, Asset B).

I envisage the following roles:

- User: can view the site in read only
- Super User: can edit asset items, edit location of the asset
- Administrator: can do everything a super user can but also add new users and assign them assets that they can view

My two avenues I have thought of so far are

**Option 1**

- Change the `aspnetUserRole` table to include the `AssetId`
- Override the `SignInManager` and change `IsInRole` to check whether the user has the role for the `assetId`. The `assetId` is stored in a claim.

The downfall of this is that for the role admin anyone with this would need to be added to each location which seems a bit painful.

**Option 2**

Policies, I am wondering if this is the better option but I am not sure how to structure it to be user friendly.

I am thinking of the policies:

- Can Edit Items
- Can Edit Locations
- Can View Item
- Can View Locations

I would then need a new table connecting the Policy, Asset and user to determine which policy they have for each asset.

However how should I handle admin who should get to do anything? Would it be as simple as a policy called `SiteAdmin` which is granted access everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try add another claim `Asset` to the user

```
//For SuperUser:
var userclaim = new Claim("Asset","AssetA");
//var userclaim = new Claim("Asset","AssetB");
.......

//For Administrator
var userclaim = new Claim("Asset","AllAsset");

// add the claim to User
var claimresult = await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, userclaim);
```

add roles to User:

```
 await _rolemanager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
 var addroleresult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
```

Regist the policies:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        .......
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AssetA",
            policy => policy.RequireClaim("Asset", "AssetA", "AllAsset").RequireRole("Admin", "SuperAdmin"));
            options.AddPolicy("AssetB",
            policy => policy.RequireClaim("Asset", "AssetB", "AllAsset").RequireRole("Admin", "SuperAdmin"));
            options.AddPolicy("SuperAdmin",
            policy => policy.RequireRole("SuperAdmin"));
        });
    }
```

Tested with the controllers：

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AssetA")]
        public IActionResult AssetA()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [Authorize(Policy = "AssetB")]
        public IActionResult AssetB()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [Authorize(Policy = "SuperAdmin")]
        public IActionResult SuperAdmin()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Result：

[image]

[image]

[image]